# Помогите с выборкой из MySQL только новых значений php js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

На данный момент имею систему сообщений которая каждую секунду посылает запрос в бд и выводит все сообщения. Мне необходимо сделать только вывод новых сообщений из бд. Сначала не повторяющийся функцией вывожу все сообщения, и каждую секунду необходимо послать запрос который возьмёт из бд только новые значения. Как это можно реализовать? Возможно есть свойство такое в sql или подскажите способ реализации на ajax jQuery. То есть нам нужно каждую сек посылать запрос с выборкой только новых значений в бд. И потом получить массив с этими сообщениями и циклом вывести его это я смогу. Главное нужен запрос на новые записи MySQL.

Comment: *Мне необходимо сделать только вывод новых сообщений из бд.* Определите точно, какие сообщения, по какому точно признаку, считаются новыми.

Comment: Во первых посмотрите в сторону сокетов...каждую секунду запрос - это жестко, потому что сообщений будет много. Во вторых отобразите модель сообщения, и по какому признаку вы считаете что оно новое

Comment: Сам признак то и нужен)

Comment: isNew колонку добавить с True по дефолту и ставить ей False  после SELECT не пойдет? Ну и далее выбирать только с isNew = True. А вообще выше правильно написали - сокеты